# Echo not working in PHP for !is_numeric

Tags: php, html, post, isnumeric

I have a simple textbox in HTML which takes only integers, they have to be EXACTLY 6 characters. If these conditions arent met, there should be appropriate messages given to the user and the value shouldnt be $_POST'ed.

```
$idLength = strlen($_POST['customerid']);

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
if(empty($_POST['customerid']))
    {
        $idErr = " *Enter ID";
    }
else if(($idLength > 0) && ($idLength < 6))
       {
       {$idnErr = " ID must be exactly 6 Digits";}
       if((!is_numeric($_POST['customerid'])))
       {$idnumErr = " ID must only be numerical values";}
       }

else if ((is_numeric($_POST['customerid']))&&($idLength = 6)) 
    {
        $id = $_POST['customerid'];
    }
echo "$id";
```

So with that code, i check if the input box is empty, if it is, it displays '*Enter ID' next to the box. I check if the value is greater than 0 and less than 6 (maxlength = 6 in html), if it is, it says "ID must be exactly 6 Digits". I also check if the characters are numbers, if they arent, it displays 'ID must only be numerical values'.

If the user enters a vaild ID, only then is the id stored in the variable. For example:- 123456. All this seems to work fine.

My problem occurs when i enter exactly 6 characters that arent meant to be taken such as, 12345a or ABCDE3. The code doesnt store them into $id but it doesnt show an error message like its meant to, i was wondering what i am doing wrong.

I also want to save the input by the user in the textbox if they enter it incorrectly. For example. if the user enters '1234g' in customer id and click submit, i want it to be there in the text box when the page refreshes with the errors.

Comment: you have an undefined variable in your code

Comment: @Daan You keeping it a secret and not telling us? ;)

Comment: what variable is undefined? @Daan

Comment: they are all defined, i just didnt add them here as there is no need

Comment: `$idLength = strlen($_POST['customerid']);` you should paste this inside server_method post. `$_POST['customerid']` is not defined

Comment: tried that before and now. no errors came up when i entered '12345f'

Comment: The variable is not defined 'Before' the post. What error reporting do you have on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over here:

```
($idLength = 6)
```

You are *assigning* the value `6` to the variable. You should be doing:

```
($idLength == 6)
```

`==` is a [comparison operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) and checks whether's it's *equal to* 6.

Comment: i have tried that before, thats what i thought it was before but that isnt the problem. I just tried it again and it didnt make the errors come up.

Comment: @roro Ok you seem to be missing a last `else` for case where the `length>6` but not numeric and I removed a redundant `is_numeric().` Have a look at this **[code.](https://eval.in/146465)**

Comment: thanks for that, i understand what i was doing wrong